# Play Store reports APK not designed for tablets, all permissions set as not required

Tags: android

Every solution I've seen on here for this problem just involved writing "androidrequired="false"" after each uses-permission that may not be avaliable on a tablet. I did this for every single uses-permission in my manifest (alot, I know), but still getting the "Your APK should only require hardware features that are usually available on tablets" on the Google Play publisher's console, and tablets are still unable to download my application. What's causing this?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.app"
    android:versionCode="21"
    android:versionName="1.01R" >

    <!-- My App requires Android APK Level 16 (4.1) or above -->
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="24" />

    <!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="false" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" android:required="false" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" android:required="false" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.myapp.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:required="false" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" android:required="false" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="false" />

    <!-- Core function permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" android:required="false"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" android:required="false" />

    <!-- Main activity. -->
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/newlogo2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:allowBackup="false"

         >
         <!-- Google Play Services Library. -->
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <!-- Register Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.app.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.app.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>



        <!-- Google Cloud Messaging Receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.myapp.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Device Administration Receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.myapp.app.DeviceAdmin"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                       android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
                <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED" />
                <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
            </intent-filter>           
        </receiver>

        <!-- GCM Heartbeat Alarm Receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.myapp.app.GCMHeartbeatAlarm"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
            android:process=":remote"> 
        </receiver>

        <!-- Receiver called on successful device reboot  -->
        <receiver android:name="com.myapp.app.BootReceiver"
                  android:enabled="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
                </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <service android:name="com.myapp.app.GCMIntentService" />
        <service android:name="com.myapp.app.LocationService" />
        <service android:name="com.myapp.app.AudioPlayer" />
        <service android:name="com.myapp.app.SoundRecorder" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every solution I've seen on here for this problem just involved writing "androidrequired="false"" after each uses-permission that may not be avaliable on a tablet

No solutions to anything should suggest that, as [there is no `android:required` attribute on `<uses-permission>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html).

> but still getting the "Your APK should only require hardware features that are usually available on tablets" on the Google Play publisher's console, and tablets are still unable to download my application. What's causing this?

Several of the `<uses-permission>` elements that you have (and, by `$DEITY`, you sure do have a **lot** of `<uses-permission>` elements...) imply that you need certain hardware features. For example, `CALL_PHONE` implies that you need the device to have telephony capability. Most tablets lack this.

For those permissions, if you are willing to get by without that hardware capability, you can add `<uses-feature>` elements — which *can* have an `android:required` attribute — to say that those hardware features are not required.

A table of relevant permissions, along with the corresponding implied hardware feature, can be found in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions).

Also, please delete:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

as there is no such permission.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A couple questions to clarify: 1. Since 'android:required' is not an attribute on '<uses-permission>', none of them should have that attribute? 2. I need the <uses-permission android:name="CALL_PHONE" /> to be allowed to call phones. If I include the '<uses-feature>' 'android.hardware.telephony' with 'android:required="false", along with the permission, will Google Play declare the app compatible with tablets?

Comment: Also, what is the '$DEITY' that you refer to?

Comment: @user3878723: "Since 'android:required' is not an attribute on '<uses-permission>', none of them should have that attribute?" -- correct. "will Google Play declare the app compatible with tablets?" -- it will certainly help.